# Using Ruby in an Elixir umbrella appp

Tags: ruby, heroku, elixir

I am running an Elixir umbrella app on Heroku.  All is fine but one thing. I am using `:erlport, github: "hdima/erlport"` to run some Ruby code (`asciidoctor-latex`). This works locally but not on Heroku.  (Heroku cannot help me as they do not support Elixir.)

I have narrowed the problem down to a single line. The app in question is http://notefile.herokuapp.com (`https://github.com/jxxcarlson/ns_umbrella`) and the line of code is in `app/apps/ruby_bridge/priv/ruby/asciidoc.rb`:

```
# require 'asciidoctor-latex'
require "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/asciidoctor-latex-
b5c9de1363de/bin/asciidoctor-latex"
```

The commented-out line works locally but not on Heroku. The other line is one of my (failed) experiments to supply`require` with a absolute pathto `asciidoctor-latex`.

I know that this line is the guilty party for the following reason. First, comment out all `require` lines; then,in `asciidoc.rb`, use `result = "Text length = #{text.length}"` instead of `result = Asciidoctor.convert text, { 'dialect' => 'latex' }`

Here I have replaced the call to a method in asciidoctor-latex by generic Ruby code. With these changes in place, the app does not crash and gives the expected output.

CONCLUSION: `require` cannot find its target. Below I've listed the buildpacks used (in order):

```
heroku/ruby
https://github.com/HashNuke/heroku-buildpack-elixir.git
https://github.com/gjaldon/heroku-buildpack-phoenix-static
```

LOGS:

```
Rendering ... 
2017-05-02T18:52:00.071102+00:00 app[web.1]: ========================
2017-05-02T18:52:00.071023+00:00 app[web.1]: MU.RenderText in APPLICATION MU_SERVER
2017-05-02T18:52:00.071326+00:00 app[web.1]: %{mode: "show", note_id: 1065, process: :adoc_latex, public: false, user_id: 9,
2017-05-02T18:52:00.071181+00:00 app[web.1]: OPTIONS
2017-05-02T18:52:00.071327+00:00 app[web.1]:   username: "jxxcarlson"}
2017-05-02T18:52:00.071392+00:00 app[web.1]: --
2017-05-02T18:52:00.071513+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendering asciidoc-latex
2017-05-02T18:52:00.150754+00:00 app[web.1]: Hello! This is render_asciidoc
2017-05-02T18:52:00.458499+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/notes/1065" host=notefile.herokuapp.com request_id=f1ce45ba-6800-4d84-9b93-47851c0502e9 fwd="65.24.227.211" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=417ms status=500 bytes=243 protocol=https
2017-05-02T18:52:00.371673+00:00 app[web.1]: (1) Hello, I am here, in asciidoc.rb, top of file
2017-05-02T18:52:00.378538+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting MU.Server ...
2017-05-02T18:52:00.459594+00:00 app[web.1]: 18:52:00.459 [error] GenServer MUServer terminating
2017-05-02T18:52:00.459607+00:00 app[web.1]: ** (stop) {:ruby, :LoadError, "cannot load such file -- /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/asciidoctor-latex-b5c9de1363de/bin/asciidoctor-latex", ["-e:1:in `<main>'", "/app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'", "/app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'", "/app/_build/prod/lib/erlport/priv/ruby1.9/erlport/cli.rb:94:in `<top (required)>'", "/app/_build/prod/lib/erlport/priv/ruby1.9/erlport/cli.rb:41:in `main'", "/app/_build/prod/lib/erlport/priv/ruby1.9/erlport/erlang.rb:138:in `start'", "/app/_build/prod/lib/erlport/priv/ruby1.9/erlport/erlang.rb:194:in `_receive'", "/app/_build/prod/lib/erlport/priv/ruby1.9/erlport/erlang.rb:234:in `call_with_error_handler'", "/app/_build/prod/lib/erlport/priv/ruby1.9/erlport/erlang.rb:195:in `block in _receive'", "/app/_build/prod/lib/erlport/priv/ruby1.9/erlport/erlang.rb:218:in `incoming_call'", "/app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'", "/app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'", "/app/apps/ruby_bridge/priv/ruby/asciidoc.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'", "/app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'", "/app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'"]}
```

Comment: Can you post the error logs from Heroku? (I think the command is `heroku logs`) You probably need to add a Ruby buildpack as well so that the Ruby dependencies are also installed.

Comment: Here is an extract from the logs:

Comment: Note the existence of the ruby buildpack in the better formatted version above

Comment: And you get the same error with `require 'asciidoctor-latex'` + Ruby buildpack?

Comment: Yes, i get the same error

Comment: I've had the ruby buildpack there since the beginning -- but my post was so badly formatted that it was hard to read -- sorry!

Comment: Here is my Gemfile, which resides at the root of the umbrella project:
`gem 'asciidoctor-latex', :git => 'https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-latex'`

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this trying to fix a similar error in a GitHub action

For me the fix was adding `require "bundler/setup"` to the top of my ruby file. Ex:

```
require "bundler/setup"
require "prawn"
...
```

A great writeup of what `require "bundler/setup"` does: https://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-bundler-setup-process/

My specific error is below for reference

```
** (ErlangError) Erlang error: {:ruby, :LoadError, "cannot load such file -- prawn", [
"-e:1:in `<main>'", "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.5/x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'",
"/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.5/x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'",
"/home/runner/work/clarus_ex/clarus_ex/deps/erlport/priv/ruby1.9/erlport/cli.rb:94:in `<top (required)>'",
"/home/runner/work/clarus_ex/clarus_ex/deps/erlport/priv/ruby1.9/erlport/cli.rb:41:in `main'",
"/home/runner/work/clarus_ex/clarus_ex/deps/erlport/priv/ruby1.9/erlport/erlang.rb:138:in `start'",
"/home/runner/work/clarus_ex/clarus_ex/deps/erlport/priv/ruby1.9/erlport/erlang.rb:194:in `_receive'",
"/home/runner/work/clarus_ex/clarus_ex/deps/erlport/priv/ruby1.9/erlport/erlang.rb:234:in `call_with_error_handler'",
"/home/runner/work/clarus_ex/clarus_ex/deps/erlport/priv/ruby1.9/erlport/erlang.rb:195:in `block in _receive'",
"/home/runner/work/clarus_ex/clarus_ex/deps/erlport/priv/ruby1.9/erlport/erlang.rb:218:in `incoming_call'",
"/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.5/x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'",
"/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.5/x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'",
"/home/runner/work/clarus_ex/clarus_ex/apps/clarus/priv/ruby/final_report.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'",
"/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.5/x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'",
"/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.5/x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'"]}
```